# HTTP 500 in redirecting to the same jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

i am having f.jsp which returns a lists of ages(1..100) and genders(m/f) and a button GO and put it in comboboxes and i have f_m.java which is servlet which took the selected items from comboboxes and select an certain item from database and put it in table in f.jsp .. now my problem is when trying to print the table in f.jsp and HTTP 500 appears so what can i do .. here is my code 
f.jsp

```
<% List<String> sex = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("sexList"); %>
<% List<String> age = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("ageList"); %>
<form method ="GET" action="f_m" >
  <html>
    <body>
       <table>
       <tr>
                <td>Gender:</td>
                <td><select name="sex">
                    <%for(String item : sexList) { %>
                        <option value="<%=item%>"><%=item %></option><%}%>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td>age:</td>
                <td><select name="age">
                    <%for(String item : maritalStatus) { %>
                        <option value="<%=item%>"><%=item %></option><%}%>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Go" name="Go"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
                  </form>
                  </body>
         </html>
```

and f_m.java

```
String gender = request.getParameter("sex");
String age = request.getParameter("age");
if(request.getParameter("Go") != null){
  // i want to go to f.jsp to print the table 
}
```

Comment: To fix error you can rename variables but you should rewrite it with JSTL.

Comment: 500 means you have some server error. What exactly says the error? Check the log

Comment: @RomanC which variables do you mean ??

Comment: @Tarlog NullPointer Exception

Comment: @user1737422 I mean scripting variables `sex`, `age`.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the request attributes in the servlet before forwarding to the jsp. I suppose it could be something like :

```java
// prepare the attributes
int ageList = new int[100];
int sexList = new String[]{"m", "f"};
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) { ageList[i] = i + 1; }

// put them in request
request.setAttribute("ageList", ageList);
request.setAttribute("sexList", sexList);

// and forward to the jsp.
request.getRequestDispatcher("f.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two lists: sex and age. When you are trying to populate the select, you asked:

```
 <%for(String item : sexList) { %>
```

Where is declared your sexList? May be you want to iterate through sex list? I mean, try:

`<%for(String item : sex) { %>`

And the same for second list:

```
<%for (String item : age) {%>
```

You must be more explicit what are you trying to do in your Servlet. I assume your main scope is to populate two selects in a form depending on two lists: sex and age. After this you want to take 2 selected values and pass them to servlet, the servlet will make a call to a database depending on these two values and will return a row from the table. After this you want to print this row in your f.jsp. If so, get the values from the select (and populate them right, like i mentioned below) in your servlet:

```
String sex = request.getParameter("sex");
String age = request.getParameter("age");

//method to call database, i.e List<Persons> list = DBHelper.checkSomething(sex, age);

if(...){
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("f.jsp");
request.setAttribute("list", list);
rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

And i strongly recommend you to print your data based on a View. If you want to know more, read about MVC patterns.